# Mark Google Search Console noindex warnings as solved

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

In the Google Search Console I get errors about pages being set to "noindex". This is on purpose so there is no need to act here. Is there a way to mark these problems as "solved" so that the Search Console doesn't notify me about this anymore?

That way it would be more easy for me to notice at a glance if there are any real problems on my website aside from the "noindex" problems, that aren't really problems.

Answer (score 2):

We get these questions all the time. You are not the only one confused. Google should be clearer. Google uses the term error and it is confusing to some users.

These are just notices. Not errors. There is nothing else to do.

Google is not saying there is a problem. Google is simply informing you of what they found. In case you may have made a mistake, you would want to know.

In short, you do not need to tell Google anything or clear these notices.

Comment: Thank you. So it is also not possible to clear these notices?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error notices? I just checked mine and I see noindexed pages under Coverage->Excluded and the URL inspection tool specifically says it is not an error. I think it may get promoted to an error if the noindex URL is in a sitemap.

Comment: @TheKidsWantDjent Some of the things you will find as errors cannot be cleared. These are the notices and meant to be information only. So no. You cannot clear them. However, they do disappear in time. Way back when... they disappeared within a few months, however, with the new Search Console, messages seem to take longer to disappear. How fast? I have no idea. There may be some variables that I do not see. Just do not freak out about them. It is not worth missing sleep over.